# Mongo DB shell, how to count duplicate entries in a collection

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

**Mongo DB shell (by running a using a JS file):**

After running a 'find' command, 
I have to find out how many duplicate rows are there in the result.
Since the collection can have varied JSON's, I'll have to parse each JSON object for comparing.

In short, **How do I enumerate keys from a bson object?**

For example, if we look at the following 4 JSON entries:

```
// 1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "Date" : "2012-06-17",
    "k1" : "v1",
    "k2" : "v2",
    "k3" : "v3",
    "k4" : "v4",
}
// 2
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "Date" : "2012-06-17",
    "key1" : "v1",
    "key2" : "v2",
}
// 3
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "Date" : "2012-06-18",
    "k1" : "v1",
    "k2" : "v2",
    "k3" : "v3",
    "k4" : "v4",
}
// 4
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "Date" : "2012-06-18",
    "rk1" : "v1",
    "rk2" : "v2",
    "bk3" : "v3",
    "bk4" : "v4",
    "ck5" : "v5",
    "ck6" : "v6",
}
```

I want to ignore "_id" and the "Date" keys while comparing.
I want to ignore "_id", because it's mongo specific, and I want to ignore "Date", because it's my requirement.

And the key's themselves are quite varied. In each JSON document, the key names vary, and the number of key-value pairs also vary.

In the above case, I want "1" and "3" to be recognized as the same (duplicate).

How do I do this?

**How do I enumerate keys from a bson object?**

Comment: I think you could possibly run a map-reduce to achieve this ... what do you want returned?  Just an array of distinct property maps with a count for each?

Comment: check mongodb Map reduce here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `stringify` may come in handy. Let's say 1 and 3 are called `data1` and `data3`. Reset both id's and dates, and you'll be able to compare them:

```
data1._id = null;
data3._id = null;
data1.Date = null;
data3.Date = null;
var eq = JSON.stringify(data1)  === JSON.stringify(data3); //=> true
```

There's some methode called `friendlyEqual` in the shell that does the same, if I'm not mistaken. In that case, you should be able to use something like: `var eq = friendlyEqual(data1,data3);`

Comment: Actually, I get this error:  

JSON is not defined. is there anything else I need to do to use JSON object.

Comment: Try using `friendlyEqual` instead. See the shell API documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/symbols/_global_.html#friendlyEqual

Comment: is there anyway this can be done via map/reduce?
Cause the above works, but is too slow.

Comment: I suppose you could use the code for a `mapreduce` (in the `map` part) command. Check the documentation @ http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce